# WPF View and ModelView creating

Tags: c#, wpf

I'am distracted because of view and modelview objects instantiating. As an example:
I've got **view V** with a **listview LV** and a button. To the button is bound command that takes as a parametr **listview LV**. Commands **CanExecute** method checks whether **listView LV** has elements. But when i open **view V** the **view model** object creates before the **view V** does. So when **CanExecture** method checks a **listView**,  it is null and my button becomes unavaliable for ever.

How solve that problem?

EDIT:
Command implementation:

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));
        }

        this._execute = execute;
        this._canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you pls post your command implementaion / the framework you use for the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that kind of command implementation, you have to call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` manually (in your case after the list view got items).

You can also change the implementation of the `CanExecuteChanged` event to:

```
[...]

public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; } 
}

[...]
```

That implementation enbales the command manager to evaluate CanExecute automatically.

Comment: out of topic: do yuo know how to pass argument to modelview constructor when the view is creating?

Comment: @igorr: Please create a seperate question. Comments are not intended for that.